# Issue passing list of VO from JSP to action using struts 1.2.9

Tags: java, struts

I have a JSP which has two labels, four check boxes, and four text fields. Since this is a set of data and can be dynamic, these fields are stored in a value object and stored in a list, and this list is passed to the action class.

The issue is that when the form is submitted I am not able to get the updated list of values through the form into Struts. I am using Struts 1.2.9

Code snippet of JSP below:

```
<logic:iterate name="monthlyGainLossForm" property="ptcList" id="ptc"> 
<mf:td> 
  <html:text name="ptc" property="ptcName" /> 
  <html:hidden name ="ptc" property="ptcName"/> 
</mf:td> 
<mf:td>
  <html:text name="ptc" property="ptcActive" />
</mf:td> 
<html:hidden name ="ptc" property="ptcActive"/> 
<mf:td>
  <html:checkbox name="ptc" disabled="false" property="msaPtcLtcGLType" styleClass="input"/> 
  <html:hidden name ="ptc" property="msaPtcLtcGLType"/>
</mf:td> 
<mf:td>
  <html:text name="ptc" readonly="true" property="msaPtcLtcGLAmt" styleClass="input"/> 
  <html:hidden name ="ptc" property="msaPtcLtcGLType"/>
</mf:td>
```

Comment: I noticed, while formatting your code, that it appears that you have one of the </mf:td> closing tags placed incorrectly; shouldn't it be *after* `<html:hidden name ="ptc" property="ptcActive"/>`, not before it? I don't know if this is the problem, but at least it's *a* problem...

Comment: You either not submitted it or it's just won't compile. What did you try? Do you have a specific question? For better help sooner, post the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use both input types for the same field at the same time: `html:text` and `html:hidden`. Remove one of them which you don't need.

So it should be like:

```
<mf:td> 
  <html:text name="ptc" property="ptcName" /> 
</mf:td>
```

and same for rest fields.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet was not the full one. But the issue was values not getting passed to action. I fixed it by putting the below line of code in JSP. This way I will get values through form in action.

```
        <logic:iterate name="monthlyGainLossForm" property="ptcList" id="productTaxCat">
        <html:hidden name="productTaxCat" property="ptcId" indexed="true" />
        <html:hidden name="productTaxCat" property="ptcName" indexed="true" />
        <html:hidden name="productTaxCat" property="ptcActive" indexed="true" />
        <mf:tr>
            <mf:td><bean:write name="productTaxCat" property="ptcName"/></mf:td>
            <mf:td><bean:write name="productTaxCat" property="ptcActive"/></mf:td>
            <mf:td><html:checkbox name="productTaxCat" property="msaPtcLtcGLType" styleClass="input" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
            <mf:td><html:text name="productTaxCat" property="msaPtcLtcGLAmt" styleClass="label" style="width:100px;vertical-align:middle;" disabled="true" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
            <mf:td><html:checkbox name="productTaxCat" property="msaMthlyStcGLType" styleClass="input" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
            <mf:td><html:text name="productTaxCat" property="msaMthlyStcGLAmt" disabled="true" styleClass="label" style="width:100px;vertical-align:middle;" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
            <mf:td><html:checkbox name="productTaxCat" property="nonMsaPtcGLType" styleClass="input" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
            <mf:td><html:text name="productTaxCat" property="nonMsaPtcGLAmt" disabled="true" styleClass="label" style="width:100px;vertical-align:middle;" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
            <mf:td><html:checkbox name="productTaxCat" property="nonMsaStcGLType" styleClass="input" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
            <mf:td><html:text name="productTaxCat" property="nonMsaStcGLAmt" disabled="true" styleClass="label" style="width:100px;vertical-align:middle;" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
        </mf:tr>
        </logic:iterate>
```

Thanks for all the helpful comments.